# Выборка по двум условиям mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы, они связаны между собой один ко многим.
Таблица client содержит первичный ключ ID, а таблица orders содержит внешний ключ ID_of_client.
Мне нужно выбрать запись с таблицы client по двум условиям:
1) Если ID клиента нету в orders.ID_of_client
2) Иначе, если ID клиента существует в orders.ID_of_client тогда выборка идет по заданому условию.
Копал в сторону in, exists, case но все-рано какая-то чепуха выходит.
 Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему не сделать 2 запроса? Первый по первому условию. Второй по второму. И объединить их UNION ALL?

Comment: Чесно говоря я над таким вариантом еще не задумывался. Ща буду гуглить.) Спасибо)

Comment: Благодарен Вам за ответ. Не знал , что такая функция как union существует. Вы меня уберегли от еще нескольких часов бессмысленых поисков. Еще раз огромное Вам спасибо! :)